# find all element inside array that match specific value - mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB V: 3.6

I have an array with 6 elements, each element have 2 values: `fileName` and `count` I want to get all elements in the array that have a count of 0

I have tried to use this code but it only returns one element, not all the elements that match.

```
await User.findOne({email:email},
                   { ackFiles: { $elemMatch: { count: 0 } } });
```

it only return this :

```
{ _id: 5b55d0fd9dc644051c801058,
  ackFiles: [ { fileName: 'terms_of_use_vad', count: 0 } ] }
```

this is how my DB looks like 
[image]

Comment: Use `find` instead of `findOne`

Comment: i tried it return same result but in an array with index of 0

Answer (score 1):

```
db.getCollection('').aggregate([{"$match": {"email": ""}},
{"$group" : {"_id" : {"email": "$email"}}},        
{
            "$project": {
                "files": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$ackfiles",
                        "as": "file",
                        "cond": {
                            "$in": ["$$file.count", [0]]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    ])
```

Comment: i tried , 
let user = await User.find({email:email},
            { ackFiles: { $elemMatch: { count: 0 } } });
        console.log(user);
        console.log(user[0]);
first console : [ { ackFiles: [ [Object] ], _id: 5b13b1f9b6fe2948b4925c69 } ]
second : { ackFiles: [ { fileName: 'list_of_features', count: 0 } ],
  _id: 5b13b1f9b6fe2948b4925c69 }

Comment: It will give you the whole document of the particular email id (which may be unique in your case) satisfying conditions for count 0 only. Its returning one doc because its satisfying both the conditions with AND operator.

Comment: i see , then if i want to get all the docs for this email that has count of 0 is there a way to do it using mongo ? or i need to make a filter my self ?

Comment: First, let me know if you have multiple entries for same email Id? Also its returning you what you require i.e. all the docs for matching email id whose ackfiles.count is 0. If you want to get all the docs with ackfiles.count 0, then you just remove the email match condition.

Comment: there is no multiple entries for same email . 
but i need to get ackfiles with count 0 for this user with this email if i remove the email i suppose i will get this for all the users in the db and i dont need this .

Comment: Hey bro!! had to put efforts for your question and i found a way via aggregation.
Please find the edit, i am getting the proper results with count 0 only in files array. You can use that array.

Comment: Hey bro , thanks for the efforts i really appreciate it , however i tried the code and it return [{_id:{email : 'email@bla.com'} , files:null }] 
i hope i did not do sth wrong 
 let x = await User.aggregate([{"$match": {"email": email}},
            {"$group" : {"_id" : {"email": "$email"}}},
            {
                "$project": {
                    "files": {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$ackfiles",  "as": "file", "cond": {"$in": ["$$file.count", [0]] } }} }}]);

Comment: Can you share a single doc of your collection, because it returned me something else.

Comment: Is this a dummy subset what you have:

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8e7fda325bec7b317b94f6"),
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "ackfiles" : [ 
        {
            "fileName" : "p",
            "count" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "fileName" : "m",
            "count" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "fileName" : "s",
            "count" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "fileName" : "r",
            "count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "fileName" : "q",
            "count" : 2
        }
    ]
}